# How to use a PHP variable which is obtained after a loop in HTML value?

Tags: php, html

This is my code :

**NON WORKING CODE**

```
<div class="myform">
<form action="blah.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php json_encode($myarr); ?>
</form>
</div>

<?php 

$myarr = array("foo");

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    array_push($myarr,$i);
    print "<div class='mylist'>$i</div>";
}
?>
</div>
```

**WORKING CODE**

```
<div class="container">

<?php 

$myarr = array("foo");

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    array_push($myarr,$i);
    print "<div class='mylist'>$i</div>";
}
?>

<div class="myform">
<form action="blah.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php json_encode($myarr); ?>
</form>
</div>

</div>
```

Now, this is more or less the situation.I cannot alter the position of the div tags as my whole website layout is based on it.How can I make sure the first one works because that ordering of the div tags keeps my web design and everything intact.

**NOTE:**  Please don't suggest me to use jQuery or Javascript.I do not wish to use them unless ther is no other way out. :(

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. You want to use `$myvar` before you define it?

Comment: How can you expect the variable to have the right value if you output it before computing such value?

Comment: Prepare your data before you start outputting it, it's that simple. Populate your array with data before any HTML is output, then just *output* in your HTML, don't change the data anymore.

Comment: There is no other way out as DOM is already generated which you need to change so you will need jQuery or javascript to do that.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: myarr in` is pretty explanatory, you're trying to access the array before you populate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With out executing of foreach you can't get that variable for encode.

```
<?php 
$myarr = array("foo");
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  array_push($myarr,$i);
}
?>

<div class="myform">
<form action="blah.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo json_encode($myarr); ?>
</form></div>

<div class="myform">
<form action="blah.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo json_encode($myarr); ?>
</form></div>
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
print "<div class='mylist'>$i</div>";
}

</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense.

Comment: At last use for or foreach.

Comment: @putvande explain me how ??

Comment: For the last `for`, I would do : `foreach ($myarr as $value) { echo $value; }`

Comment: That depends on programmer how to implement that... i already written comment for use of foreach..

Answer (score -2):

```
  <?php 

  $myarr = array("foo");

  <div class="myform">
 <form action="blah.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php json_encode($myarr); ?>
 </form>
 </div>



 for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
array_push($myarr,$i);
print "<div class='mylist'>$i</div>";
}

  </div>
 ?>
```

Try this maybe. Hope I understood you...